# SQL into html cells and rows

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I have some code that shows results in a table

Right now it will show 3 cells per row.  The issue is that the first row shows 2 then creates a new row with the expected behavior fine after that.  How can I get the first row to show 3 cells

```
   if(++$cnt == 0) {
        echo '<tr>';
    } elseif($cnt % 3 == 0) {
    echo '</tr><tr>';
    }

  echo "<td bgcolor='#009933'><a href='" . $row['local_link'] . ".m4v'    name='video'>" . $row['local_link'] . "</a></td>";
  echo "<td><video width='320' height='240' controls='controls'>
  <source src='" . $row['local_link'] . ".m4v" . "' type='video/mp4' />
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video></td>";


  }
  }
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're preincrementing `$cnt` on your first line, meaning it will never be zero - unless you started it at `-1`. Try changing your first line to:

```
if($cnt++ == 0) {
  echo '<tr>';
} // etc
```

This way the value of `$cnt` is incremented *after* you compare it to zero, not before.